# Is there any speed benefit to performing your own algorithm to scramble IDs for security purposes?

Tags: hash, authorization

I am planning to implement my own very simple "hashing" formula to add a layer of auth to an app with multiple users. My current plan is as follows:

1. User creates an account at which point an ID is generated on the backend. The ID is run through a formula (let's say ID * 57 + 8926 - 36 * 7, or something equally random). I then send back to the frontend the new user ID and the new "hashed" number and store them in `localStorage`.
2. User tries to access a secured area (let's say a settings page so they can change their own settings).
3. I send the backend two values: their ID and the hashed number. I run the ID through the same formula to check it matches the hashed value I've received. If the check passes, they can get in. So if someone has tried, say, changing their ID in `localStorage` to get access to another user's settings page, the only way they could achieve that is if they guess what the formula was. They could easily guess a user ID, but guess that the corresponding number is the result of ID * 57 + 8926 - 36 * 7 seems pretty unlikely.

I'm doing this because it would be quicker/cheaper than a db lookup for an actual hashed value... I think? Would it make more sense to use a package to create some kind of primary key/uuid instead of "hashing" a value myself and doing a db lookup each time?

I see a lot of posts saying "don't roll your own" -- is this absolute? Is it worth slowing your app down if you're dealing with relatively insensitive data?

Tech stack: React on FE, Python on BE, SQL db.